# QtCreator, ROS, and slots

Tags: ros, qtcreator, cmake, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to a build a gui using the roscreate-qt-pkg in QtCreator. In trying to generate code using "Go to Slot..." in the template, I get the following:

**No documents matching 'ui_main_window.h' could be found.
Rebuilding the project might help.**

Is this an existing issue or am I forced to manually edit the cpp and hpp files to add buttons, etc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35635/qtcreator,-ros,-and-slots/) by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-06-04**:
What ros version are you using - electric or fuerte? Also what do you mean by "In trying to generate code using "Go to Slot"?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2012-06-04**:
Without modifying anything, roscreate-qt-pkg on electric and roscreate-qt-legacy-pkg on fuerte should create packages that build compilable, runnable programs for you. Note that roscreate-qt-pkg on fuerte is only for catkin builds (if you don't know what that is, don't worry about it).

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-06-04**:
I'm using electric. The programs compile and run fine but adding new ui elements and attempting to add code for them gives the error I stated above, when using the "go to slot" option when right clicking a ui object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Still not sure what your 'go to slot' option is (in designer?). When adding a new button, I usually follow the process below:

- Run designer on ui/main_window.ui
- Add a new button inside designer
- Save the designer update.
- In a shell, make clean and make (regenerate the code).
- In my cpp editor, add a slot callback function in main_window.hpp and main_window.cpp

Note that the slot callback function has to be named to match the action and the name of the button you added - this is qt's auto-connect feature. If you get the name right, you don't need to do any explicit connecting of button to callback in designer or in your code.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-06-04**:
He's using QtCreator, which does the same process. The thing is that the designer file -> ui_* file conversion will be done during qmake. QtCreator should automatically call it, but if not you can still force it with a right-click on project approach.

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-06-05**:
I wonder if qmake still being run if you just open CMakeLists.txt in QtCreator.

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-06-06**:
whoops, you have the point! qmake is not called when using cmake since what qmake does in general is that interprets the .pro file and does what is said there. with cmakelists.txt it executes stuff from there

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-06-11**:
Excellent, things are making sense now. In lieu of setting up qmake as well I guess snorri's solution will work.